# How to color the triangles of a mesh?

Tags: graphics3d, color, mesh

Given a mesh, I want to assign each triangle a color.

I tried to do it in this way:

```
MeshVertices[mesh_] := First@Cases[mesh, GraphicsComplex[x_, __] :> x, Infinity]

MeshFaces[mesh_] := Block[{faces},
    faces = Cases[mesh, Polygon[x_, ___] :> x, Infinity];
    If [faces == {}, 
        faces = Cases[mesh, Triangle[x_, ___] :> x, Infinity];
    ];
    If [faces == {}, {}, First@faces]
];

bunny = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "StanfordBunny"}];

faces = MeshFaces[bunny];
nFaces = Length[faces];
faceColors = RGBColor[#, 0.0, 0.0] & /@ (Range[nFaces] / (0.0 + nFaces));

vertices = MeshVertices[bunny];
coloredBunny = Graphics3D[
    GraphicsComplex[
        vertices,
        Thread[{faceColors, Triangle /@ faces}]
    ],
    Boxed -> False
]
```

The rendering was quite slow, and the result was not what I wanted:

[image: Colored Bunny]

Are there any ways to color the bunny? Thank you.

Comment: One quick fix is to insert and `EdgeForm[None]` into your graphics expression to get rid of the many black edges. You can get polygon data also directly: `bunny = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "StanfordBunny"}, "PolygonObjects"];
{EdgeForm[None], Red, bunny} // Graphics3D`

Comment: @YvesKlett This also works! Thank you.

Comment: BTW the slow rendering is due to the less efficient rendering of many individual polygons as compared to the much more efficient `GraphicsComplex`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 69,451 different polygons in the bunny, so that is why it takes so long to plot, so let's use a simpler example with only ~1,400 polygons:

```
MeshVertices[mesh_] := 
 First@Cases[mesh, GraphicsComplex[x_, __] :> x, Infinity]
MeshFaces[mesh_] := 
  Block[{faces}, 
   faces = Cases[mesh, Polygon[x_, ___] :> x, Infinity];
   If[faces == {}, 
    faces = Cases[mesh, Triangle[x_, ___] :> x, Infinity];];
   If[faces == {}, {}, First@faces]];
donut = ParametricPlot3D[{(3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], (3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], 
    Sin[v]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> None];
faces = MeshFaces[donut];
nFaces = Length[faces];
faceColors = RGBColor[#, 0.0, 0.0] & /@ Rest[Subdivide[1.0, nFaces]];
vertices = MeshVertices[donut];
```

When you run your code, it places a black border around every triangle.  Compare these

```
Graphics3D /@ {Triangle[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 
     1}}], {EdgeForm[], Triangle[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}}]}}
```

[image: two triangles]

So you need to turn off the `EdgeForm[]` in your final line,

```
coloredDonut = 
 Graphics3D[
  GraphicsComplex[vertices, 
   Thread[{faceColors, {EdgeForm[], Polygon[#]} & /@ faces}]], 
  Boxed -> False]
```

[image: red donut]

Here is what it looks like with the borders:

[image: red donut with borders]

When you apply this to your bunny, here is the result:

[image: colored bunny]

By the way, here is slightly shorter code that produces the exact same result,

```
bunny = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "StanfordBunny"}];
colors = RGBColor[#, 0.0, 0.0] & /@ 
   Subdivide[1.0, 
    Length[Cases[Normal@bunny, Polygon[__], Infinity]]];
i = 1;
Normal[bunny] /. {Polygon[a__] :> 
   Sequence[i++; colors[[i]], Polygon[a]]}
```

The above code with replacement rule should work on many `Graphics3D` objects, like the `donut` above.  But in that case it is necessary to adjust the lighting by adding another replacement rule `HoldPattern[Lighting -> {__}] :> Lighting -> {{"Ambient", Red}}`

But since you are working on a `ExampleData["Geometry3D"]` object, you can get the polygons as a list directly and then just use `Thread` to combine them with colors. Thanks to Yves Klett for pointing this out

```
With[{pgons = 
   ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "UtahVWBug"}, "PolygonObjects"]}, 
 Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], 
   Thread[{RGBColor[#, 0.0, 0.0] & /@ 
      Subdivide[1.0, Length@pgons - 1], pgons}]}, Boxed -> False]
 ]
```

[image: red Volkswagen]

Or a one-liner to give a psychedelic bunny

```
Normal[ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "StanfordBunny"}]] /. {Polygon[
    a__] :> Sequence[RandomColor[], Polygon[a]]}
```

[image: psychedelic bunny]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Comment: Jason, what about getting the polygon data directly: `ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "StanfordBunny"}, "PolygonObjects"]`?

Comment: @YvesKlett - that does make for a shorter code, I hadn't thought of it (and then when I saw your comment I didn't want to take it in case you wanted to use it)

Comment: Na, your answer is so nice already, please feel free to include if it makes sense to you :D  Actually, your psycho bunny reminds me of my [oneliner cow](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31642/131), although that one uses `VertexColors`.

Comment: That cow is great!  I wasn't really aware of the `ExampleData["Geometry3D"]` stuff before

Answer (score 6):

Jason already said a lot of what I wanted to say, so I'll just offer this little snippet that avoids `Normal[]` chicanery:

```
gc = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "StanfordBunny"}, "GraphicsComplex"];
Graphics3D[Insert[gc, EdgeForm[], {2, 1}] /. Polygon[m_?MatrixQ] :> 
           Riffle[Table[RandomColor[], {Length[m]}], Polygon /@ m]]
```

[image: one crazily colored bunny]

---

Just for variety, here's another method for coloring the bunny. Recall that `GraphicsComplex[]` takes a `VertexColors` option to specify how the polygons within should be colored. (`Line[]` objects are not affected by this, which may or may not be wanted in an application.) Thus,

```
(* some color function that takes a point as an argument *)
woody[pt_?VectorQ] := Blend[{RGBColor[3/4, 22/41, 1/3], RGBColor[1/2, 2/9, 7/38]}, 
                            Haversine[π SawtoothWave[50 EuclideanDistance[pt,
              {0.08, 0.06, 0.08}]]]]

Graphics3D[Insert[gc, EdgeForm[], {2, 1}] /. 
           gc : GraphicsComplex[pts_, rest___] :> 
           Append[gc, VertexColors -> (woody /@ pts)], Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: wavy bunny]

Comment: ...and as much as I'm averse to self-promotion: [noisy bunnies](https://tpfto.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/bunnies.png)

Comment: What do you have against `Normal`?  `GraphicsComplex`es are great for the system I'm sure, but they're a pain to work with sometimes

Comment: Jason, "user21" and me mentioned some of the reasons in [this thread](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5883); that being said, a number of my previous Gravatars needed the services of `Normal[]` at some point, and I agree that `GraphicsComplex[]` can be difficult to manipulate for sufficiently intricate operations.

Comment: lol, user21 didn't used to have such a mysterious username I see....  And I can see the benefit now that it's pointed out